# Display shipping class name on WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Need to display the product shipping class to product page! any ideas why this is not working?

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_shipping_class', 15 );
function display_product_shipping_class(){
    global $product;

    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $product->get_product_shipping_class(), 'product_shipping_class' );

    if( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') && $term->name == $product_shipping_class ){
        echo '<p class="product-shipping-class">' . $term->name . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code. Try the following instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_shipping_class', 15 );
function display_product_shipping_class(){
    global $product;
    
    $shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

    if( ! empty($shipping_class) ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $shipping_class, 'product_shipping_class' );
    
        if( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') ){
            echo '<p class="product-shipping-class">' . $term->name . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.